# how to display image in all pages on advance custom fields in wp?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress. By luck I came to know about wordpress plugin advance custom fields through youtube. All of the tutorial I read/watched are based on home pages. For example add sliders etc.

If I have a logo in get_header() and I want it to be placed through ACF which would be displayed on complete site not only on one page. How it is possible?

I have only following code

```
<?php echo get_field('logo');?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in ACF you need to:

1. Create a new WordPress standard page (call it Homepage for example) this page wont actually be used on your site, you can set the visibility to private if you wish.
2. In ACF change the location rules of your existing image field to: if page is equal to homepage.
3. Make sure your ACF image field returns an image URL under 'Return Value'.
4. Go to your page in the WordPress admin and upload the image in the new custom field
5. Add this code to your header.php

`<?php $image-url = get_field('image-field-name', $page-id); ?>`

where 'image-field-name' is your ACF image field name and $page-id is the ID of the page you created. The page ID is in the URL when you're editing the page: /post.php?post=**357**

Also add this to header.php where you want the image to be displayed:

`<img src="<?php echo $image-url; ?>" alt="" />`

Comment: This isn't working. Can you give a code example? My Page-id is 89 and field name is logo.

Answer (score 1):

`<?php the_field($field_name, $post_id); ?>` will spit out the contents of any custom field on your site. You must specify the page id for this to work.

For Example: `<img src="<?php the_field(logo, 89); ?>"/>`

Answer (score 0):

All the template functions **(get_field, the_field, etc)** can be used to load values from another **post/page**, however, a second parameter is required to target the post.

Each **post/page** in WordPress has a unique ID which can be found in the URL when editing or found via code such as **$post->ID**.

**Display a field:**

This example will display a field value from the post with an ID of 123.

```
<p> <?php the_field('field_name', 123); ?> </p>
```

**Retrieving a field:**

This example will retrieve a field value from the post with an ID of 123.

```
    <?php

        $variable = get_field('field_name', 123);

        // do something with $variable

    ?>
```